# Segmentation fault error when returning the function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So,I am writing an interpreter for LC3b machines. I need to write a function to check whether the input is a valid opcode or not. For that, I have written a function as follows:

```
int isOpcode(char* oput)//oput=Opcode under test
{
  FILE* isa_file = NULL;
  int i,j;
  char * line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t nread;

  //printf("Entered opcode checking function \n");
  /*convert to lower case */
  //for( i = 0; i < strlen( oput ); i++ )
  //    oput[i] = tolower( oput[i] );
  //printf("Entered opcode checking function1 \n");

  /*for modularity, using the file */
   isa_file = fopen("isa", "r");
   if(isa_file == NULL)
       printf("Error in file opening\n");
   int flag;
   while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, isa_file)) != -1)
   {
       printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", nread);
       printf("%s", line);  
       //Solving the new line character problem which resulted in the improper difference of strcmp ..now it is proper...
       //char final[strlen(line)-1];
       //strcpy(final,line);
       //final[strlen(line)-1]='\0'; 
       //  printf("Entered opcode checking function2 \n");
       //  printf("%s \n",oput);
       // overwrite \n with nul-terminator
       line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
       char final[strlen(line)];
       strcpy(final,line);
       flag=strcmp(oput,final);
       printf("%s \n",oput);
       printf("flag: %d \n",flag ); 
       if(flag < 0 || flag >0)
       {
           flag=-1;
           //printf("entered 1st condition \n");
           printf("final flag: %d \n", flag);
        }
       else 
       {
           flag=1;
           //printf("entered negative \n");
           printf("final flag: %d \n", flag);
           break;
       }

   }
   printf("end of loop \n");//this is not getting printed
   fclose(isa_file);
   if (line)
       free(line);
   return flag;
}
```

Now, when I call the function with one of the valid opcodes,the function prints the final flag(=1) and then goes into segmentation fault. It doesnt even print end of loop statement. Could someone tell me what is the problem? I tried executing parts of this function in parts as separate files and it seems to work perfectly.

---

UPDATE:
The end of loop statement now gets printed on the screen when I commented out the toLower code.However,even then code then throws a seg fault. Interestingly, it throws an error only when the final flag is set to 1. Else, it works fine! I am unable to understand this strange issue!

Comment: Is not `final[strlen(line)-1]='\0'; ` off by one?

Comment: And check if `isa_file` is `NULL` after the call to  `fopen`.

Comment: `return flag;` should be after free and file close, obviously checking that the file is correctly opened and the line is allocated

Comment: `char final[strlen(line)-1];` off by 2 ==> `char final[strlen(line)+1];`

Comment: Why write a string terminator to `final[]` anyway when you just used `strcpy`?

Comment: Please edit your post and fix the messy indention.

Comment: Don't use an object named `read`, there's a function of the same name. We usually name it `nread` for number of bytes read.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'd say it's **off by two**, since the length does not include the NUL, but the strcpy does copy it.

Comment: @Jens yeah, noticed later....actually does not make sense....either....

Comment: I need the final to be less than the original length.Explanation: I am getting the string read from a file and that string has a 'newline character' at the end. To remove that, I defined another string with 1character less and then appended a '\0' to it thereby eliminating the newline character at the end. I think that solves most of your confusion

Comment: @LPs yeah! I changed that but still I am getting the same error!

Comment: @Jens changed that as well! Still getting that error!

Comment: the variable `read` is the same as the well known function: `read()`.  It is poor programming practice to declare variables with the same name as the system functions.

Comment: regarding: `for( i = 0; i < strlen( oput ); i++ )`  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` and that is being compared to the variable `i` which is an `int`

Comment: regarding: `oput[i] = tolower( oput[i] );`  the `tolower()` expects an `int` parameter and returns an `int` suggest: `oput[i] = (char)tolower( oput[i] );

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line 3) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when `getline()` fails, should check errno to determine the reason for the failure.

Comment: regarding: `strcpy(final,line);`  the length of `line` is 1 greater than the length of `final` due to: `char final[strlen(line)-1];`  so this call to `strcpy()` will write past the end of the `final` array,  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.]

Comment: this line: `printf("end of loop \n");` is not being printed because the prior `else` code block is calling `break;` which exits the loop before getting to the call to `printf()`

Comment: regarding: `if (line)
        free(line);`  the function: `free()` properly handles being passes a NULL pointer, so no need to check before calling `free()`

Comment: when calling: `getline()`, the `line` and `len` parameters should be re-initialized to `NULL` and `0` respectively before every call to `getline()`

Comment: regarding: `final[strlen(line)-1]='\0';` The length of the array is `strlen(line)-1` Lets assume that is 25. in C, an array index starts with 0 and continues to number of elements in array -1. So this statement is writing to element 25, which is past the end of the array. That is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event. Suggest: final[strlen(line)-2]='\0';

Comment: @user3629249 Update made to the post!

Answer (score 1):

After your comment I can say:

`strlen` already gives you the length of read chars `-1`, 'cause the `nul-terminator` is not counted. Moreover you cannot use `strcpy` to do what you need to do, 'cause it will copy all chars of source string into a smaller string causing UB.

What you can do is to remove the `'\n'` in the source string and then copy it, like:

```
// overwrite \n with nul-terminator
line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
// allocate new string less by one
char final[strlen(line)+1];
// allocate new string less by one
strcpy(final,line);
```

Comment: Dont you think char final[strlen(line)+1]; should be char final[strlen(line)]; I believe so since say: line=origin\n and after overwriting \n with NULL, strlen(line) will be 6. Now, I simply need to copy this into final which will be of size=6. However, i tried both of them but the error still remains!

Comment: @YashKarundia No. For a **6** chars string you need **7** chars array, because you need space for nul-terminator..

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. will not link because there is no `main()` function
3. applies all the comments

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf(), FILE, fopen(), fclose(), perror()
#include <string.h> // strcpy(), strchr()
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc(), free(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <ctype.h>  // tolower()

int isOpcode(char* oput);

int isOpcode(char* oput)//oput=Opcode under test
{
    FILE* isa_file = NULL;
    //int i;  <-- unused
    //int j;  <-- unused



    //printf("Entered opcode checking function \n");
    /*convert to lower case */
    for( size_t i = 0; i < strlen( oput ); i++ )
        oput[i] = (char)tolower( oput[i] );
    //printf("Entered opcode checking function1 \n");

    /*for modularity, using the file */
    isa_file = fopen("isa", "r");

    if(isa_file == NULL)
    {
        perror( "fopen to open 'isa' for read, failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    int flag;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t nread;

    while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, isa_file)) != -1)
    {
       printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", nread);

       printf("%s", line);

       //Solving the new line character problem which resulted in the improper difference of strcmp ..now it is proper...
       char final[ nread+1 ];
       strcpy(final, line);

       //  printf("Entered opcode checking function2 \n");
       //  printf("%s \n",oput);
       // overwrite \n with nul-terminator
       char *newline = NULL;
       if( NULL != (newline = strchr( final, '\n' ) ) )
           *newline = '\0';

       printf("%s \n",oput);
       printf("flag: %d \n",flag );

       strcmp(oput,final);
       switch( strcmp(oput,final) )
       {
            case -1:
            case 1:
               flag=-1;
               //printf("entered 1st condition \n");
               printf("final flag: %d \n", flag);
               break;

            case 0:
               flag=1;
               //printf("entered negative \n");
               printf("final flag: %d \n", flag);
               break;

           default:
               break;
        }

        free( line );
        line = NULL;
        len = 0;
    }

    if( !feof( isa_file ) )
        perror( "getline failed" );

    printf("end of loop \n");//this is not getting printed
    fclose(isa_file);


    free(line);

    return flag;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: note that the array `final[]` can be completely eliminated by doing all the processing on the array set by `getline()`

Comment: While the rest of the code seems fine, I am unable to comprehend the switch case. I want to compare the oput and final. If the two are equal, I need to return the flag as 1, else -1. In the code you proposed, the switch case doesnt perform that functionality since the strcmp wont always return a '-1'. It returns the difference between the two strings.

Comment: @YashKarundia,  Then replace the `switch()` statement with `if( 0 == strcmp(oput,final) ) { // handle match } else { // handle mis-match }`